# Printing a div in blazor

Tags: .net, blazor-webassembly

In my blazor app, onclick on a button, I want the user to be able to print a particular component. Pls how can this be done?

I've tried using Blazorprint but it's change some of the styles n the print window.

Also, I tried some solutions gotten online, the one of window.print, I created the js function inside my index.html and make a call to it using the JSRuntime and this also keeps saying the function name not found

Answer (score 4):

To enable printing of a particular component in your Blazor app, you can use the JavaScript interop feature provided by Blazor. Here's a step-by-step guide on how you can achieve this:

Step 1: Create a JavaScript function
In the `wwwroot` folder of your Blazor app, create a new JavaScript file, such as `print.js`. Inside this file, define a function that triggers the print functionality:

```
// print.js
function printComponent(componentSelector) {
  var elementToPrint = document.querySelector(componentSelector);
  if (elementToPrint) {
    var printWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
    printWindow.document.open();
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title></head><body>');
    printWindow.document.write(elementToPrint.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
  }
}
```

Step 2: Include the JavaScript file
In your `index.html` file, include the JavaScript file you created in the previous step by adding the following line inside the `<head>` section:

```
<script src="print.js"></script>
```

Step 3: Call the JavaScript function from your Blazor component
Inside your Blazor component, you can use the `IJSRuntime` service to call the JavaScript function. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button @onclick="PrintComponent">Print</button>

@code {
    private async Task PrintComponent()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("printComponent", "#componentId");
    }
}
```

In the above code, `#componentId` is the CSS selector for the component you want to print. Replace it with the appropriate selector for your component.

Note: Make sure you have imported the `Microsoft.JSInterop` namespace in your component file.

That's it! When the user clicks the "Print" button, it will trigger the JavaScript function, which opens a new window with the content of the selected component and initiates the print dialog for that window.